# List item count in Autolisp

Tags: autolisp

I need help building a function that will accept a list of items, such as `'(3 3 3 1 1 2)` and return occurrence of each item, in consecutive order. This particular list would return `'(2 1 3)`. I would like to do this in one loop.

My thoughts so far are to create a list containing the position for each item to be counted. I've done that. So now I have a list that looks like this: `'(0 0 0)` and I need to alter this list to reflect the count for each element in the list I receive. I have no idea how I will go about this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following function:

```
(defun itemcount ( lst )
    (if lst (cons (- (length lst) (length (setq lst (vl-remove (car lst) lst)))) (itemcount lst)))
)
```

This function will return a list of the number of occurrences of each item as they are encountered in the supplied list:

```
_$ (itemcount '(3 3 3 1 1 2))
(3 2 1)
```

For the ordered result, simply sort the supplied list prior to evaluating the function (but beware that `vl-sort` removes duplicate integers, so use `vl-sort-i`) e.g.:

```
_$ (setq lst '(3 3 3 1 1 2))
(3 3 3 1 1 2)
_$ (itemcount (mapcar '(lambda ( n ) (nth n lst)) (vl-sort-i lst '<)))
(2 1 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(defun SortByOccurance ( ListOfItems / *error* x item pairs sorted )
    (defun *error* ( msg / ) 
        (if (not (null msg ) )  (progn (princ "\nSortByOccurance:*error*: " ) (princ msg ) (princ "\n") ) )
    )
    (foreach x ListOfItems
        (setq item (assoc x pairs ) )
        (setq pairs (if (null item )
                    (append pairs (list (cons x 1 ) ) )
                    (subst (cons (car item) (1+ (cdr item ) ) ) item pairs)
        ) )
    )   
    (setq sorted (vl-sort pairs (function (lambda ( x y ) (< (cdr x) (cdr y)))) ) )
    (setq sorted (mapcar 'car sorted ) )
    sorted
)

( SortByOccurance (list 3 3 3 1 1 2) )
```

Comment: repeated append at end is quadratic behaviour, better avoided. instead, just cons on top the list, esp. that you're going to sort it later anyway.